# Not able to find Google Play SDK console

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-play-integrity-api

I am exploring Google play integrity  by [this link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup#use_google_play_sdk_console_recommended), but not able to find Google Play SDK Console, is it same as Google Play console or different?

Answer (score 0):

Google Play SDK Console is for SDK developers that are listed in the [Google Play SDK Index](https://developer.android.com/distribute/sdk-index).

For Android applications you have to setup the Play Integrity API in Google Play Console as described [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup#set-google-console).

Comment: So we only get access of Play Sdk console once our Sdk gets listed over Google?

Comment: Correct. That's the prerequisite to get access to Google Play SDK Console.